# Python Caldav, all calendars have None name

Tags: python, calendar, caldav, nextcloud

I'm trying to access to all events of my calendar, hosted on Nextcloud, with python and the caldav library.
With this code:

```python
client = caldav.DAVClient(url) #like "https://..../nextcloud/remote.php/dav/calendars
principal = client.principal()
calendars = principal.calendars()
```

I can access to all my calendars and iterate over it.

How I can read only a specific calendar, with the name "calendar_name"? In this case I get all calendars, even if I specify the calendar name:

```
client = caldav.DAVClient(url) #like "https://..../nextcloud/remote.php/dav/calendars/user/calendar_name
principal = client.principal()
calendars = principal.calendars()
```

If I change the last line of code with calendar_name, I get an empty array.

```
calendar = principal.calendar('calendar_name')
```

Note: I can access all calendars and events with the first code posted, but all names are "None", even if the Url is right.

Comment: Please show the code you use to access the calendar name (which is then None).

Answer (score 1):

The second snippet still gives you all calendars because you first grab the account (`.principal()`) and then you list all calendars the account has (`principal.calendars()`).

The third snippet probably doesn't work because the name (the *display name* property, not the URL path component) of the calendar quite likely isn't `calendar_name` but something like `Calendar`. Theoretically it may even be empty.

To access a single calendar using its URL this may work, didn't try:

```
client   = caldav.DAVClient(url)
calendar = caldav.Calendar(client=client, 
             url="/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/calendars/user/calendar_name")
```

Though it may be better to do something like this for various reasons:

```
client    = caldav.DAVClient(url)
principal = client.principal()
calendars = principal.calendars()
calendar  = any(c for c in calendars if c.url == your url)
```

To address your actual question, you need to add more information. If you want the (relative or absolute) *URL* of the calendar, use something like this:

```
print calendar.url
```

If you want to explicitly retrieve the calendar *display name*, this may work:

```
print calendar.get_properties([dav.DisplayName()])
```

Hope this helps.